# Jenkins Discard Old plugins Not working properly - Keep last 10 builds

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have installed Discard Old Build plugin version 1.05 in my Jenkins. I want to keep only 10 builds and discard old builds (whether success or other status).

below is my Jenkins Discard plugin setup.

[image]

Here I have selected all options in "**Status to Discard**". So the problem is it deletes all builds keeping only last 3 builds. ( i'm not sure why). If I uncheck "**success**" option, it deletes remaining builds and keeps all success builds even if it exceeds 10 builds.

In the [plugin wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Discard+Old+Build+plugin) , the option is "**Status to keep**" and not "**Status to Discard**"

How can I keep last 10 builds and delete remaining builds (Keep last 10 success builds)?

Comment: It's not a fully correct answer but in your particular case you can rely on the built-in Jenkins functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The Discard Old Build plugin is buggy and may cause the data loss.

The Configuration Slicing Plugin works for your purpose.
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Configuration+Slicing+Plugin

Please try to use the

- Discard Old Builds Slicer - Max # of builds to keep
- Discard Old Builds Slicer - Max # of builds to keep with artifacts

It supports mass configuration.